# Dielectric tensor and electron energy loss spectroscopy (EELS)

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, dielectric

Electron energy loss spectroscopy (EELS) is related to the imaginary part of the inverse dielectric function $−(^{−1}(,)).$
If the dielectric function $\epsilon(q, \omega)$ is actually a tensor and there is anisotropy in the system, which component of the tensor is used to generate EELS in calculations and which component is it that one sees in EELS experimentally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.